# Center UIPickerView in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uipickerview

I'm currently trying to insert a UIPickerView into a tableview cell after the user tapped the row above. I've already done this several times with UIDatePicker objects and it worked fine.

The view is correctly inserted into the new cell and is working as expected. However, the UIPickerView object is shifted to the left on the iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus.

Here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeFh6.png

The view is exactly inserted as the UIDatePicker, which is centered on every device.

```
if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 2 {

        var cell: UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PickerCell") as? UITableViewCell

        if cell == nil {

            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "PickerCell")
            cell.selectionStyle = .None

            // Create and add the UIPickerView object, same width as cell
            let picker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 216))
            picker.tag = 101
            cell.contentView.addSubview(picker)

            // Set the dataSource and Delegate for this picker to be the Controller
            picker.dataSource = self
            picker.delegate = self

        }

        return cell
```

Can you give me an advice what I can do to center this programmatically added object in it's cell?

Thanks,

Comment: You should provide width for he picker wrt the width of the parent view (i.e your tableViewCell) . 
Replace this line            
     `let picker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 216))`
with  
      `let picker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 216))`

Comment: just provide tableView width i.e let picker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: 216))

Comment: @JasmeetSingh: Thank you very much! You made my day. 
But could you explain me please, why this magic number (320) is working within the UIDatePicker but not UIPickerView?

DheerajSingh: Thank you as well!

Comment: In case of UIDatePicker you might have provided the Autoresizing mask to flexible width due to which it changes wrt its parent view.